# Close previous sub-menu and show clicked sub-menu with single click in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am using the code below for the side navigation menu. Each Navigation Item has sub-navigation items.

**Current Behavior**

- The Sub-navigation item does open on click but when clicked the next navigation heading, it closes the current sub-menu and requires 2nd click to open the required sub-menu. which means the user has to click twice to open the sub-menu of the desired sub-menu as click one closes the previous sub-menu and then click 2 to open the required sub-menu.
- Upon clicking the sub-menu item, the whole sub-menu get closed

**Required Behaviour**

- By Default Networking Sub-menu should open unless the user clicks another navigation heading.
- When the user clicks on one of the sub-menu items, the clicked heading and sub-menu should remain open.
- The sub-menu should open with a single click and close the other sub-menu that is opened.

### Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import userImage from "../../global/assets/img/avatar.png";
import { RiSettings2Line } from "react-icons/ri";

export const AppSideNav = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState("networking");
  const navDetails = [
    {
      navId: 1,
      navHead: "Networking",
      subNavItems: ["item 1", "item 2"],
      navLink: "networking",
    },
    {
      navId: 2,
      navHead: "Trading",
      subNavItems: ["item 1", "item 2"],
      navLink: "trading",
    },
  ];

  const toggle = (id) => setOpen(open === id ? undefined : id);

  const subNavFunction = (navLink, subNavVal) => {
    return `/${navLink}/` + `${subNavVal.toLowerCase()}`;
  };

  return (
    <div className="AppSideNavContentContainer">
      <div className="AppSideNavContentTop">
        <div className="AppSideNavContentTopWrapper">
          <div className="AppSideNavUserPicContainer">
            <div className="AppSideNavUserPic">
              <img src={userImage} alt="user-avatar" className="UserAvatar" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="AppSideNavUserNameContainer">
            <div className="AppSideNavUserName">
              <div className="AppSideNavUserNameText"> Username</div>
            </div>
            <div className="AppSideNavUserWalletId"> 0x99343</div>
          </div>
          <div className="AppSideNavUserDdIconContainer">
            <button className="AppSideNavUserDdIconContainerWrapper">
              <div className="AppSideNavUserDdIconInner">
                <RiSettings2Line />
              </div>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="AppSideNavContentBody">
        <div className="SideAppNavBodySection">
          <div className="SideAppNavLinkWrapper">
            <ul className="SideNavHomeList">
              {navDetails.map((items) => (
                <NavLink
                  to={
                    items.navHead === "Networking"
                      ? "/networking"
                      : items.navHead === "Trading"
                      ? "/trading"
                      : items.navHead === "Staking & Mining"
                      ? "/staking"
                      : items.navHead === "Smart Wallet"
                      ? "/wallet"
                      : items.navHead === "IDO List"
                      ? "ido"
                      : ""
                  }
                  className="SideNavLinkContainer"
                >
                  <div
                    className="OverFlowHidden"
                    onClick={() => toggle(items.navId)}
                  >
                    <div className="SideNavLinkItemContainer">
                      <div className="SideNavLinkItemContainerWrapper">
                        <div className="SideNavLinkItemContainerInner">
                          <div className="SideNavLinkItemContainerInnerWrapper">
                            <span
                              className={
                                items.navHead === "Networking"
                                  ? "SideNavLinkIcon PortfolioIcon"
                                  : items.navHead === "Trading"
                                  ? "SideNavLinkIcon TradingIcon"
                                  : items.navHead === "Staking & Mining"
                                  ? "SideNavLinkIcon StakingIcon"
                                  : items.navHead === "Smart Wallet"
                                  ? "SideNavLinkIcon WalletIcon"
                                  : "SideNavLinkIcon LaunchIcon"
                              }
                            >
                              {" "}
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <span className="SideNavLinkText">
                          {" "}
                          {items.navHead}{" "}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      {open === items.navId && (
                        <div className="SideNavLinkSubItemsContainer">
                          <div className="SideNavLinkSubItemsWrapper">
                            <div>
                              <span className="SideNavLinkSubItem">
                                {" "}
                                {items.subNavItems.map((navItem) => (
                                  <NavLink
                                    to={subNavFunction(items.navLink, navItem)}
                                  >
                                    <div className="SideNavLinkSubItemInner">
                                      <span className="SideNavLinkSubItem">
                                        {" "}
                                        {navItem}
                                      </span>
                                    </div>
                                  </NavLink>
                                ))}
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </NavLink>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you need, could you set up a codesandbox?

Comment: Hi @diedu, I have set up code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-wave-ru5ce?file=/src/App.js. as you can see submenu items for MENU 1 and MENU 2 are hidden, what I need is MENU 1 subitems are open by default when users visit the page. but when click on menu 2, in a single previous menu, subitems should close and open subitems for the CLICKED menu. for example, when user click on menu 2, menu 1 subitems should close and menu2 subitem to open with  the same click.

Comment: hehe I don't get what you want, I see that your current version of the codesandbox does what you are asking for https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-surf-w1p8g?file=/src/App.js, or do you need something like an accordion?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code sandbox, you need to do 2 things:

1. Initialize open with a default navID:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(() => navDetails[0].navId);
```

You can change the initial criteria to anything. If you want your data to control what is open by default, you can add a isDefault: true to the item that must be open by default and update your state initializer above.

2. change open based on selected id in toggle:

```
  const toggle = (id) => setOpen(open === id ? undefined : id);
```

Comment: I tried the code, it works without the navlink, i have updated the code here https://ru5ce.csb.app/ are you able to check why Navlink is changing to behaviour and require double click to open the sub-meny sand codebox here https://ru5ce.csb.app/

Answer (score 0):

Move  `onClick={() => toggle(items.navId)}` to your navigation heading not the container.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./nav.css";

export const AppSideNav = () => {
  const navDetails = [
    {
      navId: 1,
      navHead: "menu 1",
      subNavItems: ["submenu 1", "submenu 2"],
      to: "menu1"
    },
    {
      navId: 2,
      navHead: "menu 2",
      subNavItems: ["submenu 1", "submenu 2"],
      to: "menu2"
    }
  ];
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = (id) => setOpen(open === id ? undefined : id);

  return (
    <div className="AppSideNavContentContainer">
      <div className="AppSideNavContentBody">
        <div className="SideAppNavBodySection">
          <div className="SideAppNavLinkWrapper">
            <ul className="SideNavHomeList">
              {navDetails.map((items) => (
                <div className="OverFlowHidden">
                  <div className="SideNavLinkItemContainer">
                    <div
                      onClick={() => toggle(items.navId)} //add you click handler here 
                      className="SideNavLinkItemContainerWrapper"
                    >
                      <div className="SideNavLinkItemContainerInner">
                        <div className="SideNavLinkItemContainerInnerWrapper">
                          <span
                            className={
                              items.navHead === "Networking"
                                ? "SideNavLinkIcon PortfolioIcon"
                                : items.navHead === "Trading"
                                ? "SideNavLinkIcon TradingIcon"
                                : items.navHead === "Staking & Mining"
                                ? "SideNavLinkIcon StakingIcon"
                                : items.navHead === "Smart Wallet"
                                ? "SideNavLinkIcon WalletIcon"
                                : "SideNavLinkIcon LaunchIcon"
                            }
                          >
                            {" "}
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <span className="SideNavLinkText"> {items.navHead} </span>
                    </div>
                    {items.subNavItems.map((navSubMenu) => (
                      <div className="SideNavLinkSubItemsWrapper">
                        <div className="SideNavLinkSubItemsWrapper">
                          <div
                            className={
                              open === items.navId
                                ? "SideNavLinkSubItemInner"
                                : "DisplayNone"
                            }
                          >
                            <span className="SideNavLinkSubItem">
                              {navSubMenu}
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried the code and it works fine but without navlink. once I add the navlink it goes back to the same behavior and require double click to open. i have updated the code sandbox here https://ru5ce.csb.app/

Comment: You should open a new question, we solved the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solve your problem completely with NavLink. Fixes are mentioned below.

1. **NavLink** use only for navigation purposes. So I use that only to wrap necessary elements. That will prevent unnecessary state updates.
2. Your code always updates the `navId`, not the `navLink`. So that I initialize the state with **Networking** `navId`.
3. Remove the condition in the `setOpen` method.

**SideNav.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export const SideNav = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(1);
  const navDetails = [
    {
      navId: 1,
      navHead: "Networking",
      subNavItems: ["item 1", "item 2"],
      navLink: "networking",
    },
    {
      navId: 2,
      navHead: "Trading",
      subNavItems: ["item 1", "item 2"],
      navLink: "trading",
    },
  ];

  const toggle = (id) => setOpen(id);

  const subNavFunction = (navLink, subNavVal) => {
    return `/${navLink}/${subNavVal.toLowerCase()}`;
  };

  return (
    <div className="AppSideNavContentContainer">
      <div className="AppSideNavContentBody">
        <div className="SideAppNavBodySection">
          <div className="SideAppNavLinkWrapper">
            <ul className="SideNavHomeList">
              {navDetails.map((items, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="SideNavLinkContainer">
                  <div className="OverFlowHidden">
                    <div className="SideNavLinkItemContainer">
                      <div className="SideNavLinkItemContainerWrapper">
                        <NavLink
                          to={
                            items.navHead === "Networking"
                              ? "/networking"
                              : items.navHead === "Trading"
                              ? "/trading"
                              : items.navHead === "Staking & Mining"
                              ? "/staking"
                              : items.navHead === "Smart Wallet"
                              ? "/wallet"
                              : items.navHead === "IDO List"
                              ? "ido"
                              : ""
                          }
                          onClick={() => toggle(items.navId)}
                        >
                          <div className="SideNavLinkItemContainerInner">
                            <div className="SideNavLinkItemContainerInnerWrapper">
                              <span
                                className={
                                  items.navHead === "Networking"
                                    ? "SideNavLinkIcon PortfolioIcon"
                                    : items.navHead === "Trading"
                                    ? "SideNavLinkIcon TradingIcon"
                                    : items.navHead === "Staking & Mining"
                                    ? "SideNavLinkIcon StakingIcon"
                                    : items.navHead === "Smart Wallet"
                                    ? "SideNavLinkIcon WalletIcon"
                                    : "SideNavLinkIcon LaunchIcon"
                                }
                              >
                                {" "}
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <span className="SideNavLinkText">
                            {" "}
                            {items.navHead}{" "}
                          </span>
                        </NavLink>
                      </div>
                      {open === items.navId && (
                        <div className="SideNavLinkSubItemsContainer">
                          <div className="SideNavLinkSubItemsWrapper">
                            <div>
                              <span className="SideNavLinkSubItem">
                                {" "}
                                {items.subNavItems.map((navItem, index) => (
                                  <NavLink
                                    key={index}
                                    to={subNavFunction(items.navLink, navItem)}
                                  >
                                    <div className="SideNavLinkSubItemInner">
                                      <span className="SideNavLinkSubItem">
                                        {" "}
                                        {navItem}
                                      </span>
                                    </div>
                                  </NavLink>
                                ))}
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/tayyab-navigation-zlpyh?file=/src/SideNav.js